# how to Tag functionality in image like instagram in Android?

Tags: android

I am working on Tag functionality in android, I am not getting any idea regarding layouts to create Tag and Remove Tag like Instagram application.

Please See Images below

[Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IErWt.png)

[Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IvU3.png)

Answer (score 0):

create layout with relativelayout with imageView inside it, and create a custom layout for displaying name and programatically add and remove this custom layout to the relativelayout. Don't forget to set layout params to the custom layout.